# What could I possibly do to fix my line chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, line, linechart

I have a dataframe(accident_day) like this:

```
   year  accidents
   <chr>     <int>
 1 2018     231564
 2 2017     231007
 3 2016     229831
 4 2015     217694
 5 2019     211486
 6 2014     206033
 7 2013     203734
 8 2020     112913
 9 2021     110541
10 2012     100545
11 2022      89400
```

And I am trying to create a simple line graph for each year, but my results are not as I expected. What is my mistake?

```
ggplot(data=accident_day)+
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=year, y=accidents),color="black")
```

Comment: Could you clarify what "not as expected" means? What do you want it to look like? It looks fine on my end

Comment: Your years are `character`, is that intentional? If you convert to numeric or integer, the plot works.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `year` to integer (or numeric) and it plots:

```r
ggplot(data=accident_day) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=as.integer(year), y=accidents), color="black")
```

[image: ggplot line]

Or you can change it within the data with

```r
accident_day$year <- as.integer(accident_day$year)
```

If you prefer your x-axis to not indicate the half-years we see here, fix the axis (with `scale_x_continuous`), don't change the data.

```r
ggplot(data=accident_day) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=as.integer(year), y=accidents),color="black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(z) seq(floor(z[1]), ceiling(z[2])))
```

(or `breaks = 2012:2022` or several other ways to control the breaks of an axis).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple other options:

**Option 1: convert `year` to Date.** Dates needs a month and day as well, so we could set each year to January 1 of that year:

```
library(ggplot2)

accident_day$year <- as.Date(paste0(accident_day$year, "-01-01"))

ggplot(data=accident_day)+
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=year, y=accidents))
```

[image]

**Option 2: specify `group`:** As @r2evans points out, the reason your data don't work as-is is that `year` is a character vector, and `geom_line()` is a little particular when the x axis isn't numeric. It will consider each value its own "group" with no way to connect them. If you want to keep it as character, you can solve the problem by adding `group = ""` to the `aes()` call.

```
ggplot(data=accident_day)+
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=year, y=accidents, group=""))
```

[image]

Note this usually isn't the best approach for dates (e.g., if there's a missing year in your data, the x axis spacing will be wrong), but can be useful in other situations.